# How to grab text from a selected drop down value

Tags: c#, selenium

I have the below HTML for a drop down menu:

```html
<select class="" data-id-title="" default-selected="0" 
  data-bind="value: selectedTitle, options: titles, optionsText: 'Text', optionsValue:'ValueId',
  optionsCaption: 'Title', $el: $elTitle, hasFocus: titleHasFocus, attr: {'default-selected': defaultTitle}">
    <option value="">Title</option>
    <option value="1">Mr</option>
    <option value="2">Mrs</option>
    <option value="4">Miss</option>
    <option value="3">Ms</option>
</select>
```

I want to grab the text of the selected value of the drop down. So for example if I selected 'Mrs' from the title, I want to grab the text 'Mrs'.

Currently I am grabbing by value, so I am grabbing '2' as the output and not 'Mrs'. How do I grab the text?

Below is the code that is currently grabbing the selected drop down value:

```
public List<string> GetPassengerNames()
{
    List<string> titleList = new List<string>();

    var passengerTitles =  _driver.FindElements(PassengerDetailsElements.TitleField);

    foreach (var passengerTitle in passengerTitles)
    {
        titleList.Add(passengerTitle.GetAttribute("value"));
    }
    return titleList;
}
```

PassengerDetailsElements.TitleField is this:

```
public static By TitleField => By.XPath("//*[@data-id-title='']");
```

Thanks

Comment: Well you could set the value to be the title ..... rather than 1,2,3//

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this, first use `SelectElement` to locate the dropdown

```
SelectElement drpDown= new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//*[@data-id-title='']")));
drpDown.SelectByText("Mr");
```

for text

```
selectedValue.SelectedOption.GetAttribute("value");
```

You can use official document of the [selenium dropdown selection](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#user-input-filling-in-forms)

Answer (score 0):

1. Select this option which you want

   SelectElement selectElement = new SelectElement(element);
   selectElement.SelectByText(text);
2. After that, get a text

   new SelectElement(_casualtySearchPageElements.CasualtyWeather).SelectedOption.Text;

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute *selectedIndex* for the *select* node in order to find which option is selected. Then, you can find the corresponding text.

```
my_select = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("select")
my_select.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")[int(my_select.get_attribute("selectedIndex"))].text
```